# Showing a non-isomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

> I need to show that $\Bbb Z^*_8$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^*_{10}$.

$\Bbb Z^*_n$ means integers up to $n$ coprime with $n$

I do not know how to do this. I have difficulties doing proofs involving isomorphisms. A methodological answer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of $3$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}^*$ is $4$, while the order of elements from $\mathbb Z_8^*$ is $2$.

Comment: so to show that 2 groups are isomorphic, it suffices to show that elements have the same order?

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton No, but you're trying to show that they're not isomorphic. Having the same number of elements of a given order is necessary but not sufficient for them to be isomorphic.

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton Having a bijection is necessary, but a bijection might not preserve the algebraic structure.

Comment: @MattSamuel this is quite stupid of me, but probably my text is badly written. If I am to determine isomorphism between two finite groups, one of the things I can do is that to see that if there are say 4 elements in each of them, there exists isomorphism if there are $k$ number of elements in each group of $m$ order? Can there be isomorphism between 2 groups that are not both cyclic?

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton there are two groups of order 27 whose nonidentity elements all have order 3. One is abelian, one is not abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: see if you can show that one of these groups is cyclic, whereas the other is not.